# Rate limiting (cutting off) if exceed n connections per minute

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, proxy

What do you suggest I use to rate limit incoming http connections (get/post) based on n connections per minute?

If a particular client makes more than n connections in a given minute, drop all further connections until the minute is up.

I currently use nginx and haproxy, but I'm really looking for the best tool for the job.

**Update**

Some clients have more connections allowed per minute, would there be a way to add a per client rule?  An API would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

It depends how gracefully you want to apply the cut off. For DROP/DENY on the TCP layer you can do it with iptables with something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set  
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 -j DROP
```

You can target things to specific clients, with extra alternatives for the second rule e.g.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s 4.3.2.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if nginx supports such type of limits. However, you can use iptables `limit` module. You can look at [this page](http://linuxgazette.net/108/odonovan.html) for more explanation.

Here is an example to accept the new HTTP connections at rate of 5 conn per minute.

```
-A FORWARD -d your.server.ip.addr -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 \
   -m limit --limit 5/minute -j ACCEPT
```